# Read history commands on GNOME 2?

Tags: security, debian, gnome, logging

Someone (old employee) deleted the history record and I am wondering if there is any way to read the commands executed by Gnome ?

Thanks!

FYI:

Server: Debian 6.0 Gnome: v2

Comment: What history do you mean? A shell history?

Comment: No, for example if you delete a folder using the GUI (gNome) is there any log that saves that information ?